# How to display the user groups because they didn't show in django view?

Tags: python, usergroups, django-2.2

I research this from a couple of days but there is not so much information about the groups in django's documentation, and really can't figure out what to change so the groups will be display.

I have CRUD operations for users which can be done only from admin and he can assign users to 6 different groups. It saved in the database and everything works well. The problem I faced now is that the groups are not visualize in my views (in the UI).

I attached picture to show what I mean:
[groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euMLr.png)

**model.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    username                        = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    is_superuser                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employee                     = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_headofdepartment             = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_reception                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_patient                      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active                       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'email',
            'password',
            'group',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'] = ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Group.objects.all(),
            empty_label='Избери'
        )
```

**useradd.html**

```
<h1 class="display-4">Add new user</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save </button>
```

**users.html**

```
                  {% for user in users %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.group }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{% url 'feedback:useredit' user.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px"-0>
                                    <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                                </a>
                                <form action="{% url 'feedback:userdelete' user.id %}" method="post" class="d-inline">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn">
                                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@admin_only
def users(request):
    context = {'users': CustomUser.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'users.html', context)

@login_required
def users_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            users = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            #login(request, users)
            # redirect, or however you want to get to the main view
            return redirect('feedback:users')
    else:
        form = UserForm() 

    return render(request, 'useradd.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution if someone needs this is since Group is a many-to-many relationship with User, it needs to iterate through all the Group objects associated with each user.

```
<td>
{% for group in user.groups.all %}
{{ group.name }}
{% endfor %}
<td>
```